# Comparing two model lists and filtering their items in ExpansionListTile Dart / Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create an ExpansionList in Flutter: I have created two models **CoffeeShop** and **CoffeeShopMenu**, but the problem is that I do not want to simply display values ​​from the **CoffeeShopMenu** model as a list, that each **shopTitle** is assigned its own **shopMenuTitle** value. For example: the name "Strarbucks" belongs to 'Latte and americano', 'Dunkin doghnuts' to 'Matcha' and etc.

I understand this task this: first, I need to filter each list using the `where` method, and then pass the filtered value through the `forEach` method inside the widget, where forEach goes through each element of the **CoffeeShop** model and looks for its element in the **CoffeeShopMenu** model. Roughly speaking, I want to filter both lists with **string** values ​​by their titles. Also both models **don't** have the same ids.

But I just can't figure out how to implement it correctly, and at the moment the code looks like this:

```
class ExpList extends StatelessWidget {
  List<CoffeeShop> coffeeShop = <CoffeeShop>[
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'Strarbucks'),
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'Dunkin doghnuts'),
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'Subway'),
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'MCCafe'),
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'Coffee Shop'),
  ].where((element) => element.shopTitle == element.shopTitle).toList();

  List<CoffeeShopMenu> coffeeMenu = <CoffeeShopMenu>[
    CoffeeShopMenu(shopMenuTitle: 'Latte and americano'),
    CoffeeShopMenu(shopMenuTitle: 'Matcha'),
    CoffeeShopMenu(shopMenuTitle: 'pie'),
    CoffeeShopMenu(shopMenuTitle: 'sandwich'),
    CoffeeShopMenu(shopMenuTitle: 'croissant'),
  ].where((element) => element.shopMenuTitle == element.shopMenuTitle).toList();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: coffeeShop.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            coffeeShop.forEach((element) {
              coffeeMenu.forEach((element) {
                return coffeeMenu;
              });
              return coffeeShop;
            });
            return ExpansionTile(
              title: Text(coffeeShop[index].shopTitle),
              subtitle: Text(coffeeShop[index].shopTitle),
              children: [
                ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: coffeeMenu.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                          title: Text(coffeeMenu[index].shopMenuTitle)
                      );})],
            );
          }),
```

Is it possible to complete this task?

I was even try to merge two list, but it didn't work as I wanted. Can you, guys, help me to figure it out?

[I am trying achive something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Ldr.png)

and it also gives an error:

```
Assertion failed:
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#6b2e7 NEEDS-PAINT"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, It can be solved like this: 
So if you wanna separate depend on each one so appreciate to each one then you have to provide a variable like `store` in your `CoffeeShopMenu` by doing this, we can create correct list to display in `ExpansionList`.

**Your models should be like:**

```dart
class CoffeeShop {
  final String shopTitle;
  const CoffeeShop({this.shopTitle});
}

class CoffeeShopMenu {
  // So we providing a variable to assigne store.
  final String store;
  final String shopMenuTitle; 
  
  const CoffeeShopMenu({this.store, this.shopMenuTitle});
}
```

**Your `ExpList` should be like:**

Note: add `shrinkWrap: true` to your `ListView.builder` which is used in `ExpansionList` to solve the hasSize issue.

```dart
class ExpList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExpListState createState() => _ExpListState();
}

class _ExpListState extends State<ExpList> {
  List<CoffeeShop> coffeeShop = <CoffeeShop>[
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'Strarbucks'),
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'Dunkin doghnuts'),
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'Subway'),
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'MCCafe'),
    CoffeeShop(shopTitle: 'Coffee Shop'),
  ];

  List<CoffeeShopMenu> coffeeMenu;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: coffeeShop.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          
          // Here we are initilazing the coffeMenu lsit 
          // with store values.
          coffeeMenu = <CoffeeShopMenu>[
            CoffeeShopMenu(
              store: coffeeShop[0].shopTitle,
              shopMenuTitle: 'Latte and americano',
            ),
            CoffeeShopMenu(
              store: coffeeShop[1].shopTitle,
              shopMenuTitle: 'Matcha',
            ),
            CoffeeShopMenu(
              store: coffeeShop[2].shopTitle,
              shopMenuTitle: 'pie',
            ),
            CoffeeShopMenu(
              store: coffeeShop[3].shopTitle,
              shopMenuTitle: 'sandwich',
            ),
            CoffeeShopMenu(
              store: coffeeShop[4].shopTitle,
              shopMenuTitle: 'croissant',
            ),
          ];
          
          // Then you have to create a correctItems list
          // to display it in ExpansionTile
          List<CoffeeShopMenu> correctItems = coffeeMenu
              .where((e) => e.store == coffeeShop[index].shopTitle)
              .toList();

          return ExpansionTile(
            title: Text(coffeeShop[index].shopTitle),
            subtitle: Text(coffeeShop[index]. shopTitle),
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true, // make shrinkWrap true to solve the problem 
                itemCount: correctItems.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(correctItems[index].shopMenuTitle),
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank ypu for your full explanation @theiskaa, but can I ask another question? I am a noob in Flutter hehe. So if I use a Future provider for getting json and  how can I do this for such a filtration? I was trying to filter like this: List<CoffeeShopMenu> stop = Provider.of<List<CoffeeShopMenu>>(context). where((element) => element.store = e.store == coffeeShop[index].shopTitle).toList(); but it says index isn't exist and it use this line for filtration

Comment: Hey, @theiskaa can I ask you another dumb question? so if I don't want  to make list manually by it is index (cuz there can be a lot of elements), what should I do? Now I did such thing: I make the common class, compare two lists and trying to sort elements as it shows on screen by using the variable and taking each element by where method. If  have a little time, can I ask you to see what I am asking for on GitHub? https://github.com/loonyfawn/flutter_filtered_shop